# Any limitation on number of s3 lifecycle rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I want to move some millions of s3 objects to glacier.

```
path/to/object1/1.jpg
path/to/object2/2.jpg
...
```

So I will set s3 lifecyle rules like this.

```
Rule 1
prefix: path/to/object1/1.jpg

Rule 2
prefix: path/to/object2/2.jpg

...

Rule n
prefix: ...
```

Is there any limitation on number of lifecyle rules?

Target objects have no common pattern on path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is admittedly a little bit elusive in the documentation, but it is mentioned here:

> An S3 Lifecycle configuration can have up to 1,000 rules. This limit is not adjustable. The `<ID>` element uniquely identifies a rule. ID length is limited to 255 characters.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html

Each bucket can have only 1 lifecycle configuration (or none), so that's your limit.

Comment: Thanks really helpful

Comment: I can't find any of this information in the provided link

Comment: @GovindSingh https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rule-id